# How to calculate due date for rent in php

Tags: php

This is my code in which I am calculating the due date for according to current date.
If user shift on 2nd Feb than according to current date the due that will be show 1st June.

```
  $current_date=date('Y-m-d');
  $ref_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ref_date));

  if($current_date>$ref_date){

  $ref_month=date('m', strtotime($ref_date));
  if($ref_month=="12"){
      $ref_new_year = strtotime("1 year", strtotime($ref_date));
      $due_year=date("Y", $ref_new_year);
   }else{
      $due_year=date('Y', strtotime($ref_date));
   }

    $due_day=date('d', strtotime($ref_date));
    $due_month=date('m', strtotime($ref_date));

  $check_year=$due_year."-".$due_month."-".$due_day;

    $shift_month= date("m", strtotime($ref_date));
    $current_month=date("m", strtotime($current_date));
    $my_month1=$current_month-$shift_month;
    $my_month=$my_month1+1;

    $your_date1 = strtotime("$my_month month", strtotime($ref_date));
    $due_month1= date("m", $your_date1);
    $due_month121= date("M", $your_date1);

    $due_day1=date('d', strtotime($check_year));

    $check_month=$due_year."-".$due_month1."-".$due_day1;

    $ref_date12 = strtotime("-1 day", strtotime($check_month));
      $due_date11= date("d", $ref_date12);
      $ref_final_date=$due_year."-".$due_month1."-".$due_date11;

      $ref_date11=date('d', strtotime($ref_final_date));
      $current_date=date("d", strtotime($current_date));

    if($current_date<$ref_date11){
      $your_date1321 = strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($ref_final_date));
      $due_month22= date("M", $your_date1321);
      echo $final_date=$due_date11."-".$due_month22."-".$due_year;
    }else{
        echo $final_date=$due_date11."-".$due_month121."-".$due_year;
      }

}else{
  //Year
  $ref_month=date('m', strtotime($ref_date));
  if($ref_month=="12"){
      $ref_new_year = strtotime("1 year", strtotime($ref_date));
      $due_year=date("Y", $ref_new_year);
    }else{
      $due_year=date('Y', strtotime($ref_date));
    }

    $due_day=date('d', strtotime($ref_date));
    $due_month=date('m', strtotime($ref_date));

    $check_year=$due_year."-".$due_month."-".$due_day;

    //Month

    $ref_month = strtotime("1 month", strtotime($check_year));
    $due_month1= date("m", $ref_month);
    $due_month1321= date("M", $ref_month);
    $due_day1=date('d', strtotime($check_year));

    $check_month=$due_year."-".$due_month1."-".$due_day1;

    //Date

    $ref_date12 = strtotime("-1 day", strtotime($check_month));
    $due_date11= date("d", $ref_date12);

    if($current_date < $ref_date){
      echo "Tenant not shifted yet.";
    }else{
      echo $final_date=$due_date11."-".$due_month1321."-".$due_year;
    }
}
```

In this code I am facing the problem where if the user shift date was 1st March then the due is coming as 31st June but June is of 30 days only. Kindly help me.

Comment: Can you explain what the rules are on which your calculations are based? Is this same legal requirement? What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

You are using date functions it is interesting because php does consider there is no 31 june

If you can comment on your code we can help further

If you want to do on the long-way you can do -1 days if month 4, 6 etc (30 day months)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mktime()` function to build the future date based on current date/time.  Simply add 30 to the days argument when you call the function.

Note that I'm using `intval()` because there isn't a `date()` format string that doesn't have a leading 0 for these date parts, which confuses some versions of PHP as to its "integer-ness".  If all you care about is the date and not time, feel free to hard code a value like `1` instead of using the `date()` calls to get the hours/minutes/seconds part.

```
<?php

$hours=date("G");
$minutes=intval(date("i"));
$seconds=intval(date("s"));
$month=date("n");
$day=date("j");
$year=date("Y");

$today=mktime($hours,$minutes,$seconds,$month,$day,$year);
$futureDate=mktime($hours,$minutes,$seconds,$month,($day+30),$year);

print("Today is ".date("n-j-Y",$today)."<br />\n");
print("in 30 days it will be ".date("n-j-Y",$futureDate)."<br />\n");

?>
```